# Hadoop schedule jobs to run sequentially (one job after other)?

Tags: hadoop

Lets say I am resource constrained in my Hadoop environment and I don't want to schedule really long running jobs (ie takes days to complete). I am analyzing vast amount of past time series data. I want to schedule mapreduce jobs that take a day's worth of data at a time (which takes an hour to crunch).

So how do I schedule such that new job is submitted as soon as previous job is completed?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to run a job every 24 hours?

Comment: Not really.. I am not trying for something like cron... I want to schedule the next one, only if the previous is completed and so on for a handful of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick and simple approach you could just write a shell script that calls `hadoop jar` in sequence for each job you want to run.

If you want a more robust approach you could use [Apache Oozie](https://oozie.apache.org) to define a [workflow](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html) of jobs that will run your jobs in sequence. If you are new to Hadoop you may find it easiest to define and run your Oozie workflow using the [Hue GUI](http://gethue.com).